# Using for loop for statistics by data frame column in R

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics

I have been trying to make a loop that takes a vector of the column names I want to use and then does a loop for statistical tests to a column that determines the group of the sample. Here is how it looks for now.

```
sink('df_statistics.txt')

df <- `df.tsv`

columns <- c("column1" , "column2" , "column3" , "column4")

for (x in columns) {
    wilcox.test(formula = x ~ Group, data = df)
}

sink()
```

When I run it I get this error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = data ~ Group, data = df) :
>   variable lengths differ (found for 'Group')

My groups are determined by the numbers 1 and 2. 
I also tried naming them control and experimental but I keep getting the same error as above. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `for (x in columns) {x1 <- df[c('Group', x)];;wilcox.test(x=x1[,1], y = x1[,2]) }` or perhaps `lapply(df[columns], function(x) wilcox.test(x~df$Group))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply`

```
lapply(df[columns], function(x) wilcox.test(x~df$Group))
```

#### data

```
columns <- c("column1" , "column2")
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(Group = rep(1:2, each=5), column1 = rnorm(10), column2 = rnorm(10))
```

Comment: I substituted the variables with the ones I have but this error shows up. Error in [.data.frame(df, columns) : undefined columns selected. @akrun

Comment: @user3930423  It means those columns are those in the dataset.  I have showed a reproducible example that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't programmatically access the columns with the original notation.  Use the [[ ]] notation to select the desired column with a variable.
Try:

```
columns <- c("column1" , "column2" , "column3" , "column4")

for (x in columns) {
    wilcox.test(formula = df[[x]] ~ df$Group)
}
```